# How to put the month name in sequence?

Tags: mysql

I have drawn a chart like this:

[image]

How I want to arrange the month in sequence from january to december?

And how I want to insert month with no data inside the chart?

This is my sql.

```
SELECT ljj.job_id
     , SUM(CASE WHEN ljj.job_type = "0" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS jobcount
     , SUM(CASE WHEN ljj.job_type = "1" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS interncount
     , MONTHNAME(FROM_UNIXTIME(ljj.job_timepublished)) AS month
FROM {local_jobs_job} ljj 
INNER JOIN {local_jobs_location} ljl ON ljj.job_location = ljl.location_id
INNER JOIN {local_companydetail} lc ON ljj.job_company_userid = lc.userid 
WHERE lc.link = "1"
GROUP BY MONTHNAME(FROM_UNIXTIME(ljj.job_timepublished))
```

Comment: Omitting the job_id from the GROUP BY clause is courting disaster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `GROUP BY MONTHNAME(FROM_UNIXTIME(ljj.job_timepublished))` with `GROUP BY MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(ljj.job_timepublished))` should do the trick

Comment: `ORDER BY MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(ljj.job_timepublished))`

Comment: when use order by it will not give the result. only one month appear

Comment: Oh then use `GROUP BY MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(ljj.job_timepublished))`

Comment: ok..I see. GROUP BY MONTH works. I mistakenly put GROUP BY MONTHNAME which makes it not arranged. How to put in the other months which don't have data inside so that the chart will show from jan to dec?

Comment: Thanks @styl3r for your help

Comment: Do you know how to display other months in the chart?

Comment: Depends on the chart library you're using